# Camel - How to use an object that is inside the object sent on body to do splitting

Tags: apache-camel

Maybe this is a very dumb question but It will help to clarify my understanding of camel. I have a seda queue where I insert objects of type FromData. FromData has a method

```
public GenericFile<File> getFirstFile () {
    return files.values().iterator().next();
}
```

Now in my route I want read from the queue and split the contents of the file.

I came up with this solution. Are there a better way to refer to `body.firstFile`, other ways of doing `.split(simple("${body.firstFile}"))`

```
public void configure() {
    from("seda:processReceiver")
    .split(simple("${body.firstFile}"))
    .split(body().tokenize(",")).streaming()
    .process(new Processor() {
         public void process(Exchange msg) {
             System.out.println(msg.getIn().getBody());
         }
    });
}
```

Comment: Would `.transform(simple("${body.firstFile}"))` or `.setBody(simple("${body.firstFile}"))` work?

Comment: Great, setBody worked. This is the accepted answer! Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would suit:

```
.setBody(simple("${body.firstFile}"))
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Actually, author did indeed say this is the solution. Refer comment: "This is the accepted answer! Thanks".